# how to upload a file to java server(MultipartEntity) using curl php

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I'm developing a web portal which is consuming the REST API from java. By using curl I'm able to send post request and receive response easily but I'm not able to send file using CURL, it shows the error "**HTTP Status 500 - Could find no Content-Disposition header within part**":

Here is my code:

```
 $filename  = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'];
 $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
 $data      = '@'.fread($handle, filesize($filename));
 $dat = base64_encode($data);
 $POST_DATA = array(
   'imageName' => $dat,
     "Id" => "690",
 );
 $boundary = '--myboundary-xxx';
 var_dump($POST_DATA);
 $params = json_encode($POST_DATA);

 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost.com/Project/REST/webservice/saveImage');
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary; ',  
 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename:"$filename";',
 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params) 
 )); 
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

 $response = curl_exec($curl);
  var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl));

 curl_close ($curl);
 var_dump($response);
 echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you try

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary.'; ',
    'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.';',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params)
));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. i tried but its not working.